# How to make create form on Laravel Nova shown as modal

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I'am recenly used laravel nova as my CMS. but I still confuse to create modal when `create resource button` clicked. I was tried to use `Resource tool`  but I got error the resource not found.

my goal, just want to displaying `create user form` as a modal. so,  when user click `create user` button in this following image. popup will shown instead of redirecting to another page
[image]

anyone can help me, please.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This old Nova plugin still works, (Nova 3.29), though it's hardcoded for a primaryKey of `id` and has a few minor bugs.

https://github.com/ahmed-m-hussain/nova-Hasmany-To-Modal-Popup